# Stack View causes buttons w/ image to go off screen in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, xcode, uistoryboard, uistackview

I'm currently making a type of soundboard in Xcode, and I'm trying to get four buttons that all contain the same image to line up with each other horizontally, and have four rows line up vertically in a 4x4 grid.  So after I resize all my buttons on my storyboard, I attempt to embed them all in a Stack View.  However, upon doing this, the buttons DO line up horizontally, BUT the buttons resize themselves and the Stack View stretches way offscreen.  I'm unable to resize the stack view in the storyboard.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: add constraints to the stackview

Answer (score 0):

A stackView cannot display a grid. It can either contain horizontal or vertical components. Select the first row, put it in a stack view. Do the same for next three. You should now have four horizontal stack views. Now embed these four stack views in another stack view with vertical components.
Lastly, set up your constraints and you should be good to go.